# Calculate the postion of an object, via 2 cameras

Tags: position, computer-vision, triangulation

Best

In the following image, you can view the setup of my problem.
In general, i've 2 cameras which have a view-angle of 48° and 64°.
Secondly, I know the position of my camera's (which means i can calculate the distance between the two cameras )
And Thirdly, I know the angle (alpha) of my object for each of the cameras

Now the question is: Can I know all the other things? Like the distance of the purple dot according to the blue dots. (+ also the position)

Kind regards

**EDIT**

Without knowing the angle between the camera-view-angle and the Red line

[image]

Comment: I think the answer to this question should give you an answer to yours, as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36666585/how-can-i-measure-distances-in-stereo-images

Answer (score 0):

If you know the angle of each camera from the red line connecting them, then you have everything you need.

Assume the length of the red line is L and the distance from the purple dot to the red line is D.

Let a = the angle formed from the red line to the line connecting camera A to the purple dot.

Let b = the angle formed from the red line to the line connecting camera B to the purple dot.

Now, a and b can easily be calculated as you know each camera's angular range, its angle from the red line, alpha1 and alpha2.

The distance D is given by:

```
D = L.sin(a).sin(b)/sin(a+b)
```

Comment: What do you mean with : 
Now, a and b can easily be calculated as you know each camera's angular range, its angle from the red line, alpha1 and alpha2.

- does it mean that i've to know the angle of the red line and the first line of the view angle of the camera? (I actually would like to avoid this ... )

Comment: if you " know the angle (alpha) of my object for each of the cameras" by which you mean a1, a2 then a above is 90-48+a1; otherwise clarify what you mean you know the alpha